# What is this require syntax?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I am a bit confused on some syntax of `import` and `require`. Sometimes I see the syntax such as this:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
```

What does this means in this case, `react-native` is put into the `React` variable, and then the `var { ...} = React` means then we choose only those components to be used in the project?

Sometimes I also see the following syntax:

```
import {
  Animated,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
```

What is the difference between those two, are they similar, what should I use by preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Per the link:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

So for example:

```
var { a, b } = {
  a: 3,
  b: "foo"
}
```

Will give you:

```
a = 3
b = "foo"
```

Now, regarding `require`. The `require` function returns a *module object*, which is just an object with all the exports as properties. Using destructuring assignment will unpack those exports (because they are properties of the module object) and give you only certain name exports of a module.

Now onto [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax. Though this might seem like it's destructuring assignment, it isn't. It is one of `import`'s many syntaxes that imports named exports from a module. Essentially it does the same thing as the above but it is *not destructuring assignment*. Both options allow you to do the following. Consider a module named `square`:

```
//square.js
export function square(n) {
    return n * n;
}
```

I could do:

```
var module = require("path/to/square.js"); //require returns an object that has all the exports attached as properties
module.square(3); //9
```

Or:

```
var { square } = require("path/to/square.js"); 
square(3); //9

import { square } from "path/to/square.js";
square(3); //9
```

The difference between those last two is that one is ECMAScript 2015 and the other is ECMAScript 5. It really doesn't matter because they both import a specific name from a module.